# Msys shell command to change the attributes of a file

Tags: mingw, msys, file-attributes

Please let me know a MSYS shell command that can be used for changing the attributes of a file. When I ran a command as `ls -l` I got the following :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 lenovo Admin .....m4sugar.m4
```

I want to provide full access rights.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood you right, but anyway check for `chmod`.

Comment: i used chmod 777 m4sugar.m4 and it displayed what i have written

Comment: And who's the owner of the file? I it you? Try `sudo chmod` or `su` and the `chmod`. Both will require a `su/root/admin` password.

Comment: From memory, I don't know if `chmod` is actually effective on Windows; I'm not sure how accurately NTFS ACLs are represented as Unix-style permissions, nor if they can be changed through that interface.

Comment: @cdhowie is right: `chmod` has no real effect on Windows: you need to either either `cacls` or `icacls` (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3):

@cdhowie is right; this is a bug of msys tracked there ->
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=102435&aid=3071537&group_id=2435

> It cannot do anything more useful than it already does, unless it fakes it
>   in the POSIX emulation, as Cygwin does. However, what Cygwin does is
>   mostly irrelevant; since MSYS was forked from Cygwin-1.3, most of that
>   faking was *deliberately* disabled -- it *isn't* an objective of MSYS, to
>   provide faked POSIX features to the extent supported by Cygwin. If you
>   want Cygwin's behaviour, and MSYS doesn't retain it sufficiently for your
>   needs, then you should use Cygwin.
>
> MSYS is designed to better integrate with the *native* MS-Windows features
>   supported by MinGW. In this native MS-Windows environment, there is no
>   file system attribute which can mark a file as executable -- that is
>   indicated by magic byte sequences within the file's data space, (and
>   usually also qualified by a file name extension to match). There is no way
>   MSYS chmod can safely modify that, without risk of file corruption, other
>   than by more completely embracing Cygwin's emulation. However, that is
>   diametrically opposed to the MSYS Project objectives -- it just ain't going
>   to happen.

@kbulgrien gives the good approach to change the permissions:

- `cacls`: http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html, or
- `icacls`: http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html

*Note: `icacls` is the new version of `cacls` correcting several issues but seems to be not present in Windows XP.*

You can use either of the following commands to give full access rights to Everyone:

- `cacls "$file_path" //E //P Everyone:F`
- `icacls "$file_path" //grant Everyone:F`

Note that `ls -l` in Msys won't display accurate information on real ACLs after the usage of `cacls` or `icacls`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very likely one of the minimal implementation in MSYS tools.  You would also be restricted from making changes you cannot change with a Windows tool like attrib.exe.

```
$ >test
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r--    1 kbulgrie Administ        0 Aug 24 13:51 test
$ chmod u-w test
$ ls -l test
-r--r--r--    1 kbulgrie Administ        0 Aug 24 13:51 test
$ chmod u+w test
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r--    1 kbulgrie Administ        0 Aug 24 13:51 test
```

As you can see, chmod works fine.  Now, see what happens with attrib.exe, a Windows binary:

```
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r--    1 kbulgrie Administ        0 Aug 24 13:51 test
$ attrib +R test
$ ls -l test
-r--r--r--    1 kbulgrie Administ        0 Aug 24 13:51 test
$ attrib -R test
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r--    1 kbulgrie Administ        0 Aug 24 13:51 test
```

attrib, the Windows tool, is agnostic about the ugoa permissions and simplifies things down to having or not having rights:

```
$ attrib +R test
$ attrib test
     R     C:\msys\1.0\home\kbulgrien\test
```

I'm note sure its fair to expect an MSYS tool to do more than the Windows "equivalent".    The M in MSYS means "Minimal".

cacls.exe can do some things under MSYS.  For instance, this says I and Administrators have full control even though `ls -l` appears to say Administrat doesn't have write.  Be careful.  If on Windows, perhaps use Windows methods.
    $ cacls test
    C:\msys\1.0\home\kbulgrien\test BUILTIN\Administrators:F 
                                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F
                                    APD\kbulgrien:F 
                                    BUILTIN\Users:R

The following command is one I use in an MSYS environment to fix permissions on SQL database files after I restore from archive.  You can run Windows binaries from MSYS.  I do it all the time... for instance, scripts run diskpart, format, etc. in an MSYS shell without invoking cmd.exe.

```
$ cacls "Mantis*.*" //E //G "NETWORK SERVICE":F
```