# How to set a file to write-only or read-only in Msys or Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, msys, file-attributes

The function `chmod` is implemented in **Cygwin** but does not fully match access rights in Windows. This appears in the following change log: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-new1.7.html

> Since 1.7.34, chmod does not always affect the POSIX permission mask
>   as returned by stat(2) or printed by ls(1), due to the improved POSIX
>   ACL handling. However, that's still far from perfect, so, as a
>   temporary workaround, [...]

The implementation of `chmod` in **Msys** is not working, as mentioned in the following bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1475/

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915178/msys-shell-command-to-change-the-attributes-of-a-file) is asking how to provide full access rights to a file in Msys.

How can I change the rights of a file to respectively "read-only" and "write-only" in Msys/Cygwin?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the commands provided by windows: `cacls` and `icacls`

More information on these commands:

- `cacls`: http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html or [technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732245(v=ws.11).aspx)
- `icacls`: http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html or [technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.11).aspx)

It is now recommended to use `icacls` to change permissions easily:

- **Read-only**:  `icacls "<file_path>" /grant:r Everyone:R`
- **Write-only**:  `icacls "<file_path>" /grant:r Everyone:W`
- **Full access**: `icacls "<file_path>" /grant Everyone:F`
- **No access**: `icacls "<file_path>" /deny Everyone:F`

*Note: the option `:r` make the new Permissions to replace previously granted explicit permissions*

If you want to hide the output of the command (details about "processed file xxx" and "Successfully processed ... Failed processing ..."), then you can redirect the standard output to "null" as such:

- In Cygwin/Msys: `icacls ... 1>/dev/null`
- In Windows Command Line (cmd): `icacls ... 1>null`

---

If you want to keep a compatibility with **Windows XP**, you will have to use the older `calcs` instead by typing 2 lines:

**Read-Only** with `cacls`

```
$ cacls "<file_path>" //E //P Everyone:N 1>/dev/null
$ cacls "<file_path>" //E //G Everyone:R 1>/dev/null
```

**Write-Only** with `cacls`

```
$ cacls "$file_path" //E //P Everyone:N 1>/dev/null
$ cacls "$file_path" //E //G Everyone:W 1>/dev/null
```

*Notes:*

- *The first line removes all rights (the equivalent of `:r` in `icacls`).*
- *The second line adds either "Read" or "Write".*