# msys2 set executable permission so that commands auto-complete

Tags: msys2

I would like to be able to do the equivalent of `chmod +x file.sh` on msys2. This would appear to be possible in some way, since executable files that I have checked out of git have a "+x" permission. But new files that I create for myself do not.

I have read answers such as this: [Msys shell command to change the attributes of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915178/msys-shell-command-to-change-the-attributes-of-a-file)

I realise that msys2 is minimal and does not directly map permissions to windows ones, and that the "+x" permission will not make the file executable or otherwise. But what msys2 gives as the permission seems to affect completion. It is irritating to have some `files.sh` autocompleting on tab and some not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For scripts, ensure that they begin with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). For shell scripts, try:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This should cause MSYS2 to believe the file is executable, and allow tab completion.

Comment: This does indeed appear to work, and is a lesson not be so lazy in future.

Comment: This is also why MSYS2 'ls' on a network drive is so slow, and why a directory listing in a OneDrive folder causes every file to download locally.